# Trouble getting two separate forms, (on different pages), to work on Netlify with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, forms, gatsby, netlify

The Netlify site name is: https://southsidepaint-prototype.netlify.app
I am using React with Gatsby and Sass, all up to date with the latest versions.

I have a simple contact form on the contact page (’/contact’) that looks like this:

```
    <form name="contact-form" method="POST" data-netlify="true" >
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact-form" />
        <div className={ctSty.formGroup}>
          <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required/>
        </div>
      <div className={ctSty.formGroup}>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      </div>
      <div className={ctSty.formGroup}>
        <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
      </div>
      <div className={ctSty.formGroup}>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type='submit' value="Submit">Send message</button>
    </form>
```

Now this form above is submitting correctly, didn’t work with a honeypot or recaptcha but that’s ok. The problem is when I click to submit my other form which exists on a separate page (’/careers’), I receive no 404 errors, no warnings, nothing happens. I check the deploy log for warnings too, only had one warning: “warning undefined”; I’m not sure where this particular warning comes from but it existed before the forms were added, so I think that’s ok too. Netlify is able to see that I have a second form, I have the folders on my forms page but nothing is being submitted in spam or verified. I have scoured through the docs, videos and articles but cannot pin down a fix.
Things I have tried:

I have even reduced my second form down to three simple inputs, name, email and phone number and still the same result.

I have changed the name attribute in my form multiple times, cleared the cache on deploy.

changed the name from “form-name” in my

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="applicationsV2" />
```

Added an “onSubmit” to the form

```
<form name="applicationV2" method="POST" data-netlify="true" onSubmit="submit">
```

The second form’s code is below:

```
  <form name="applicationV2" method="POST" data-netlify="true" onSubmit="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="applicationsV2" />
        {/* FULL NAME  */}
      <div className={crSty.formGroup}>
        <label for="name" required>
          <span><CgAsterisk /></span> Full Name <br/>
          <input name="Full_name" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Phillip Anthropy" required/>
        </label>
      </div>
        {/* EMAIL ADRRESS  */}
      <div className={crSty.formGroup}>
        <label for="email" required>
          <span><CgAsterisk /></span> Email Address <br/>
          <input name="Contact_email" type="email" placeholder="e.g. user@email.com" required />
        </label>
      </div>
      {/* PHONE NUMBER  */}
      <div className={crSty.formGroup}>
        <label for="phone" required>
          <span><CgAsterisk /></span> Phone Number <br/>
          <input name="Contact_phone" type="tel" placeholder="e.g. 555-0000" required/>
        </label> 
      </div>
   </form>
   <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
       <button type='submit' value="submit">SubmitApplication</button> 
   </div>
```

Comment: The form name `applicationV2` is different than the hidden input value `applicationsV2`. There's an extra s.

Comment: Yikes, good catch. I can't believe I missed that. I am greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your second form (`applicationV2`). While in the form name appears `applicationV2`, in the value of the `form-name` field is `applicationsV2`. It should be:

```
  <form name="applicationV2" method="POST" data-netlify="true" onSubmit="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="applicationV2" />
```

Keep in mind that with your previous snippet your form was in a kind of limbo because there wasn't a match between forms names so, the data was sent but never caught by any Netlify form. Fixing the typo should fix your issue too.

For further logs, check the Network tab in the inspector tools to see whats Netlify returning in the form response.